# Proof that a continuous map to $S^n$ whose image is a proper subset of $S^n$ is null-homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am attempting to prove the following:

If $g:X \to S^n$, $n \ge 1$, is a continuous map whose image $g(X)$ is a proper subset of $S^n$, then $g$ is null-homotopic.

Just before this I proved that if $Y$ is contractible, then every continuous map $f:X \to Y$ is null-homotopic.  Therefore I'd like to show that any proper subset of $S^n$ is contractible.  What is the best way to do this?  I wanted to use that $S^n$ is an $n$-manifold to associate it with an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which, if it is convex, is contractible.  However, I don't think this works, and it seems like overkill anyway.

What is the best way to show that a proper subset of $S^n$ is contractible?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not true that any proper subset of $S^n$ is contractible!! What *is* true is that $S^n - x$ for any point $x$ is contractible, and that is enough.

Comment: @Dylan: Of course, I should have realized that...  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Not all proper subsets of $S^n$ are contractible (unless $n = 0$ obviously). Take any two unequal points $x \neq y \in S^n$, then $\{x,y\} \subset S^n$ is not contractible.

What is true is that $S^n \setminus \{ x \} \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible, so if the map isn't surjective, it factors through a contractible space so it's nullhomotopic.

Comment: Can you explain to me why $\{x,y\} \subset S^n$ is not contractible again? Why couldn't you have a homotopy that slowly moves one point to the other point?

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom The homotopy you are thinking about shows that the inclusion $i : \{x,y\} \to S^n$ is homotopic to a constant map. Instead, actually write down what the definition of "contractible" is. You want the identity $\operatorname{id} : \{x,y\} \to \{x,y\}$ to be homotopic to a constant map. In other words, you want a continuous function $H : \{x,y\} \times [0,1] \to \{x,y\}$ such that $H(x,0) = x$, $H(y,0) = y$, and $H(x,1) = H(y,1)$. Such an $H$ doesn't exist.

Comment: So the ambient space doesn't matter then, okay.

Comment: There is no such thing as an ambient space in general.

Answer (score 0):

If $g\neq a\in S^n $ use

$ H(x,t )=\dfrac{ tg(x)+(1-t)a}{ \|  tg(x)+(1-t)a\|}$

Comment: Is there no possibility that $tg(x)+(1-t)a$ is zero?

Comment: Edited, thanks.